# How are Multi-Touch Buttons implemented in the Android Calculator?

Tags: android, button, calculator, multi-touch

I recently bought a Nexus 7 and noticed that the built-in Android Calculator uses multi-touch buttons.  From what I understand, the only way to do this is to capture all your events in one view and pass them to the sub-views yourself.  Like so:

http://www.passsy.de/multitouch-for-all-views/

However, I've searched through a few code repositories and cannot see anywhere the Android Calculator is doing such work, which leads me to think there's an easier way:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.1.1_r1/com/android/calculator2/Calculator.java?av=f

Does anyone see how the Android Calculator is implementing multi-touch buttons?

Comment: If you place 2 `Button`s in a layout they can be touched simultaneously without adding any code.

Comment: @zapl Thanks for the reply, but I have never seen this happen.  I don't know of any other android UI element that works this way either.

Comment: about ten year pass, this question still not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I recently stumbled upon the answer.  As [zapl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/995891/zapl) pointed out, muliple buttons in a layout can be touched simultaneously, without adding any special code.

However, my app had a target API of 10 and this did not work.  Changing my target API to 15 suddenly worked on my ICS and newer devices.  I'm not sure if a target API of Honeycomb(11) would work, but 15+ did.